# How to draw shader / image by data using gpu in moderngl?

Tags: python, gpu, shader, python-moderngl

So I am working on a raycasting project and first of all I need to know is how to render shader / image using GPU and moderngl on python.

```py
import moderngl
def noise(size):
    return [(random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(size)]

width, height = 100, 100
data = noise(width*height)

...
```

How to render the `data` on screen in a window using gpu and how to dynamicly change it (for example regenerating noise every second?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @G.M. I did everything in one file, so previous attempts are now erased.

Comment: Then you should probably start by reading the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/moderngl/) which appears to include plenty of examples.

Comment: @G.M. I couldnt find anything, I was sitting for about two hours now, but I still can't find anything. Evrything uses GLSL programs and other stuff that I don't understand.

Comment: If you're going to achieve anything with OpenGL then I'm afraid you'll have to learn about shaders and GLSL -- there's really no two ways about it.  Have a look at [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders) (it's C++ oriented but the principles are the same regardless of language binding).